# Control font for annotation in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've a plot and I've used `annotate` to add some indications.

However, it is not using the general font used for the theme: Roboto, from `hrbrthemes`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(hrbrthemes)

ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat, y = y)) + geom_col() +
  theme_ipsum_rc(grid="XY") +
  labs(title = "My plot title using Roboto") +
  annotate(
    geom = "text", x = 3, y = 10000, 
    label = tt, hjust = 0, vjust = 1, size = 6,
    family= "Roboto", 
    size= theme_get()$text[["size"]]/2.5, 
    fontface="italic")
```

I've tried to set the family font in the annotate function call.

Other way would be to use:

```
family= theme_get()$text[["family"]]
```

So the annotation gets the font family from the general plot (Roboto), but this is giving me:

```
Warning messages:
1: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
  font family not found in Windows font database
2: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
  font family not found in Windows font database
3: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
  font family not found in Windows font database
4: Duplicated aesthetics after name standardisation: size
```

**Howcome is this possible if the title is using the Roboto font?**

[image]

**UPDATE 1:**

Have installed extrafont library, imported the fonts and registered them:

```
font_import()
fonts()
loadfonts()
```

But still cannot set the font for `annotate` function. all fonts are registered:

```
font_import()
C:\Windows\Fonts\Roboto-Black.ttf : Roboto-Black already registered in fonts database. Skipping.
C:\Windows\Fonts\Roboto-BlackItalic.ttf : Roboto-BlackItalic already registered in fonts database. Skipping.
C:\Windows\Fonts\Roboto-Bold.ttf : Roboto-Bold already registered in fonts database. Skipping.
C:\Windows\Fonts\Roboto-BoldCondensed.ttf : Roboto-BoldCondensed already registered in fonts database. Skipping.
C:\Windows\Fonts\Roboto-BoldCondensedItalic.ttf : Roboto-BoldCondensedItalic already registered in fonts database. Skipping.
C:\Windows\Fonts\Roboto-Italic.ttf : Roboto-Italic already registered in fonts database. Skipping.
C:\Windows\Fonts\Roboto-Light.ttf : Roboto-Light already registered in fonts database. Skipping.
C:\Windows\Fonts\Roboto-LightItalic.ttf : Roboto-LightItalic already registered in fonts database. Skipping.
C:\Windows\Fonts\Roboto-Medium.ttf : Roboto-Medium already registered in fonts database. Skipping.
C:\Windows\Fonts\Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf : Roboto-MediumItalic already registered in fonts database. Skipping.
C:\Windows\Fonts\Roboto-Regular.ttf : Roboto-Regular already registered in fonts database. Skipping.
C:\Windows\Fonts\Roboto-Thin.ttf : Roboto-Thin already registered in fonts database. Skipping.
C:\Windows\Fonts\Roboto-ThinItalic.ttf : Roboto-ThinItalic already registered in fonts database. Skipping.

loadfonts()

Roboto already registered with pdfFonts().
```

**Update 2:**

Just with plain ggplot2, I cannot set the font for annotate neither.

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat, y = y)) + geom_col() +
  labs(title = "My plot title using Roboto") +
  annotate(
    geom = "text", x = 3, y = 10000, 
    label = tt, hjust = 0, vjust = 1, size = 6,
    family= "Roboto")
```

Gives:

> Warning message: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text,
>   as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :   font family not found in
>   Windows font database

***Plots renders with another font in the annotation***

Comment: hrbrthemes uses [extrafont](https://github.com/wch/extrafont)

Comment: Sorry, I've got a mac, on which just passing `family = "Roboto"` to `annotate` does the trick, so I don't think I'll be able to help. You could try adding the variant, e.g. `"Roboto-Medium"`? But that's a wild guess.

Comment: In case of the plain ggplot2: Put `extrafont::loadfonts("win")` at the top of your script so that fonts are loaded before (!!!) ggplot2 is loaded. Learned this when I started using extrafont package somewhere else on the Internet. This worked for me. I also tested with "Roboto Mono". Also. When using hrbrthemes I got warnings too. But these were related to the fact that I have not installed Roboto Condensed on my machine. Everything worked finde when setting the base_family argument to "Roboto" or "Roboto Mono". Hope this helps.

Comment: @stefan this worked also with `hrbrthemes`. Thank you.